# How do I test updating a service worker in a development environment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, service-worker

What I'd like to achieve is the ability to push a notification to the user when an update is available to my React webpage, and I am trying to do so via serviceWorkers.

The challenge I am facing is to get the installation property of the serviceWorkerRegistration interface to not return null. I just want to trigger 
`console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')`

I am quite new to working with serviceWorkers in React. Does anyone have an idea on how to go about testing the update functionality of serviceWorkers in a development environment?

```
  console.log('I am in registerValidSW!')
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      console.log(registration)
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing //This returns null
        if (installingWorker) {
          console.log('installingServiceWorker!!!')
          installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
            if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
              if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
                // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
                // It's the perfect time to display a 'New content is
                // available; please refresh.' message in your web app.
                console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
              } else {
                // At this point, everything has been precached.
                // It's the perfect time to display a
                // 'Content is cached for offline use.' message.
                console.log('Content is cached for offline use.')
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

@krish according to new documentation-> The service worker is only enabled in the production environment, e.g. the output of npm run build. It's recommended that you do not enable an offline-first service worker in a development environment, as it can lead to frustration when previously cached assets are used and do not include the latest changes you've made locally. refer this link :- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

Comment: The OP wasn't asking if you should enable service workers in dev but rather how to test a service worker in development if you are not supposed to activate them